# How to implement this sticky-header scroll-down component?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `div` container that is about 70% of the height of the page. The 30% which is outside the `div` is dim lighted (greyed out).

I am trying to implement a functionality where scrolling down within this container `div` causes the container `div` to fill up more of the page (less vertical space is greyed out) and eventually all of it (so 100% height).

Vica versa, when scrolling upward within the container and reaching the top should cause of the greyed out space to become bigger. What is the easiest way to implement this, possibly with the help of a library?

Comment: Would it be relevant to add some code to your question? This can often make your problem easier to understand for others.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wd5YgvKgZCn1G_lpuqYsJJ84cs7LMo2i

Comment: I have a video demonstration

Comment: @D.Richard, try to include part of your html & css file in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `scroll` event and a combination of `scrollTop`, `scrollHeight` and `clientHeight` properties, we could get something that resembles your need:

```js
let elem = document.querySelector('div');

elem.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  if(elem.scrollTop == 0) { 
    elem.style.height = `${elem.clientHeight + 10}px`;
  }
  if(elem.scrollHeight - elem.clientHeight == elem.scrollTop) { 
    elem.style.height = `${elem.clientHeight + 1}px`;
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #555;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

div {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 70%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>
</body>
```